# Is it 'an hotel' or 'a hotel'

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-article, accent

In a book I saw this statement.

> Before words beginning with *h* and not accented on the first syllable, an is often used ; as,

> An historical , an hotel.

I want to know whether h in hotel is pronounced or not.
I would be really grateful if someone can explain this more.

Comment: Some (specifically, [Jeremy Paxman](https://brandonrobshaw.wordpress.com/2017/03/14/an-historic-occasion-sic/)) ridiculously pedantic Brits (not Americans, I don't think) still say ***an historic occasion***, but that's about the only case where it's even remotely "correct" to use ***an*** before a word starting with aspirated /h/. Americans don't always pronounce the /h/ in ***herb***, so they might refer to ***an herb*** where Brits would say ***a herb***.

Comment: I don't know about 'pedantic' - what if it's how you were brought up? It's awfully hard to break some of these habits. I hope you wouldn't call a Cockney/Estuary person 'common' or 'sloppy' for saying 'I wear an 'at when it's cold'.

Comment: I do not think an historic event is pedantic. the an comes out as un, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pronouncing the 'h' in 'hotel is a choice. In modern times in the UK, 'hotel' is very often pronounced with the 'h' sounded, so that the correct preceding indefinite article is 'a'. However, older people, especially of the middle and upper classes, may be used to pronouncing the word with a silent 'h', and thus would use 'an' before. This was common in the 18th and 19th centuries. Another word of this type is 'historic'. This dropped 'h' is not to be confused with the working-class or Cockney 'h' dropped from most words starting with that letter, very common in the UK.

[A hotel or an hotel](https://wordwatchtowers.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/a-hotel-or-an-hotel/)

Comment: It's because _hotel_ was originally thought of as a French loanword and therefore pronounced with a silent 'h' as in French. (The older borrowings _hostel_ and _hostelry_ always have the 'h' sounded.)

Answer (score 1):

In American English, the h in hotel, historian, etc. is pronounced. Silent initial 'h' is not a feature the way it is in some dialects of British English, though there are a few words that have it. The debate over a/an before pronounced h has pretty firmly settled on a, and not an. It would strike me as old-fashioned and pretentious for someone to use "an historian," and just plain wrong for someone to use "an hotel."

Comment: I say both, and although I am possibly a bit old-fashioned, I am not in the least 'pretentious'. Just a middle-class English person born in 1952.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I'm sure that's true! My comment is about an American context, where the only people I've heard using "an historian" are self-aggrandizing history professors.